# Facebook GameRequest tracking on Android

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook SDK 4 for Android to send GameRequest along with custom item. That works fine but how do I track that the request was accepted so that I can give that item to the recipient?

When I tap the request in native Facebook app then it shows the app which sent the request and I can tap 'Play' which opens up Google Play store app with that app (even though the app is installed on the device) and since the app is not yet in the store - it says 'Item not found' (that is understandable).

As per Facebook docs, if the app has presence on Canvas then it receives GET params with request IDs but I could not find how this works on mobile. The app is not launched directly so how am I supposed to find out whether the user accepted the request?

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:name=".AppEntry" .... >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</aplication>
```

In Facebook dashboard the Google Play package is the same as in the AndroidManifest and Class Name is specified to .AppEntry, yet still the app is not launched directly but goes into Google Play store app instead.

Comment: You should put in a fully qualified class name, like com.your.package.AppEntry

Comment: Yes, it works when putting in a fully qualified class name, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenter [Ming Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647528/ming-li) provided the correct answer:

> You should put in a fully qualified class name, like com.your.package.AppEntry